# Ansible - using include_role from within an include_tasks action

Tags: ansible

I have a file containing some tasks. One of the tasks in this file uses include_role to execute a bunch of tasks from a role.

```
# tasks.yml

- name: task-1
  include_role:
    name: my-role

- name: task-2
  ...
```

I have my main playbook which calls the tasks in tasks.yaml from a with_items loop:

```
# main.yml

tasks:
  - name: main-task
    include_tasks: tasks.yaml
    with_items: "{{ items.values()|list }}"
```

When this playbook is run I get the following errors:

```
ERROR! 'include_role' is not a valid attribute for a Play.
The error appears to have been in '.../tasks.yml': line 1, column 3, but may be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.
The offending line appears to be:
  - name: task-1
    ^ here
```

Ansible appears to not like the way include_role is being used in the tasks file. I am not sure if the syntax is wrong somewhere or if doing it this way is not supported. Any ideas?

Comment: If you want to run all tasks of the playbook "tasks.yml" from "main.yml", I guess the proper way to do this is to do a "- import_playbook: task.yml" on "main.yml" instead of that task.

Answer (score 0):

Test it with anither role first. I would remove the with_items for include as second option, may not work.